# How change 2 for iterators in 1 line

Tags: python, loops

I have these 2 iterators:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_routes)):#
    for b in range(len(lines)):         
        r = lines[b].find(list_of_routes[i])
```

How can this be simplified?

P.S.

For example:

```
list_of_routes = [route1, route2, route3]
lines = [info for route1, info for route2, info for route3, info for route2]
```

Comment: Can you provide the ```lines``` and ```list_of_routes```

Comment: `for i in range(len(x))` can almost always be simplified to `for item in x`.  If you really need the index variable, the pythonic way is `for i, item in enumerate(x)`.

Comment: How much more simple are you expecting it to be?

Comment: you could use for loops over the actual items in list instead of an index to "simplify". But my bigger concern would be efficiency. Seems like one of those lists should be hashed up as a dict.

Comment: If these two lists are meant to be iterated over in parallel, you can use the bulit-in `zip` function: `for route, line in zip(list_of_routes, lines):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

for route, line in product(list_of_routes, lines):
    r = line.find(route)
```